# What is this pilot doing before boarding his F-15?

Tags: feature-identification, aircraft-operations, f-15

In this video ...

[Fast takeoff of an F-15 Eagle from an air base in Iceland](https://youtu.be/KYIBX2n9TPs?t=50)

... what is this one thing the pilot does on arrival, before climbing the ladder?

It looks like he's putting something, about the size of a video cassette, in a panel.

[image: putting something, about the size of a video cassette, in a panel]

I think there's a brief view of the same when driving:

[image: brief view of the same]

Comment: Because you mention a cassette (I couldn't get a good look), from the sister site Retrocomputing, *if* it is what I think it is: [How did this coordinate capture peripheral work?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12358/15267)

Comment: Thanks. What do you think it is? The cassette shown at time 7:17 of that video looks like more like an audio cassette. But I'd forgotten it may be 50-year-old technology. And the flight plan is something that would plausibly arrive with the pilot.

Comment: It is a video casette containing a King Schools episode related to the flight the pilot is about to take. The video will play on the radar screen by selecting the "ALT VID KNG" mode on the master switch. The reason the tape deck is not placed in the cockpit is that during the development phase of this system, there was a malfunction that lead to the tape being flung out of the cassette. Pilot got so badly tangled up in it he had no other choice than to eject. Emergency crew spent hours cutting him free, luckily no permanent injuries were sustained.

Comment: It could be either for mission [data recording](https://www.airforce-technology.com/contractors/flight-data-recording/calculex/) or [data transfer](https://rochesteravionicarchives.co.uk/collection/mission-systems/data-transfer-cartridge). If someone knows where the corresponding units are located.

Comment: @Jpe61 Or just some music, like in Iron Eagle

Answer (score 5):

That's the door for the video tape recorder.

Referenced here, on an F-15 forum:
https://www.ar15.com/forums/general/F-15-scramble-training-in-Iceland/5-2469550/

That location changed between F-15 versions. IIRC, our F-15C/D at Soesterberg was in the cockpit.

Comment: Is it actually limited to video? Can't audio and data [be recorded too](https://www.airforce-technology.com/contractors/flight-data-recording/calculex/)?

Comment: @mins - That one is video, and probably audio.. Capturing the HUD, and a front facing vid camera. The video in the post was from an F-15C at Keflavik Iceland, long before comprehensive solid state capture as in your link. Keflavik stood down in the mid 90's. It was literally video tape, about the same size as a VHS.

Comment: It looks distinctly smaller than VHS, more like [Betamax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betamax).

Comment: This is the camera (or at least one possible camera): https://www.photosonics.com/f-15cd_msip_hud_camera.htm.  I think there's a bit on the older model AVTR here: https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/424/0000/Recent-Advances-In-Airborne-VideoData-Recording/10.1117/12.936195.short but I don't have access.  Budget for replacing them with digital units https://www.saffm.hq.af.mil/Portals/84/documents/FY10/AFD-090511-091.pdf?ver=2016-08-23-091915-880 (page 206/210)

Comment: One doc suggests that (again some models) may have had the photo-sonics SVCR-V301, which if https://www.parttarget.com/5836-01-307-3865_5836013073865_SVCR-V301-A.html/-03CBA3A4-046B-4318-B423-162343E4730E is correct was in fact a (S?)VHS tape.

Comment: If it's a tape recorder why on earth would it be the pilot's job to put the tape in?

Comment: @ChrisW - Because it is also his job to take it out at the end of the flight, and go to debrief with it. His flight, his recording.